# SSIS Package Logging for an intermitantly hanging package- Which Events should I Log first?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an SSIS package that is run via SQL Agent every 3 minutes throught the day, this package has not changed in months, but recently we have experienced intermittant issues where the package is kicked off but never completes and does not exit with failure(So sql agent does not notify us and does not log any failure). The failure is very seldom (less than once a day in an average week). However it used to happen *Never*, and when it does happen now it locks up production and causes many angry phone calls.
 The Package is fairly Straight forward. [image]

In the above image:

1. Pull data from two production sources into a temp table, make sure the temp table is clear first
   The sources are OLE DB sources (Sql databases) and the destination is same.
2. On Success, clear the target table in our data warehouse, and populate it from TEMP.

The queries that read from production are liberally sprinkled with (no lock) hints, but I don't think locks are the problem.. If they were, wouldn't the package fail and SQL agent show our source object as a deadlock victim?

I'd like to enable SSIS package logging to get more details - but I want to minimize the over head since this job runs so frequently. Which event in SSIS package logging are my best bets to start with?

Comment: Instead of killing it, why not inspect your servers (source and destination) and see what is happening. `sp_whoisactive` is your search term. You might be blocked but not *deadlocked*. Since you don't know which step in there has you hung up, I'd suggest starting with OnPreExecute/OnPostExecute. That way you at least see the start and stop time for individual tasks. When you kill it, you will see what operation is was working on. Rudimentary

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for the tips! - I've never heard of sp_whoisactive before now (turns out I Do live under a rock, who knew?), and unfortunately I'll not be allowed to implement it in our production system (the source). But I surely will on the destination side (our data warehouse). I look forward to using it to investigate other problems in the future. Mean time I'll start a SSIS package log with the OnPreExecute/OnPostExecute details as you suggested.

Comment: If you have access to the system DMVs that sp_whoisactive uses, you can strip out the CREATE/ALTER and just run the guts of the script. As an itinerant developer, I keep a no-install copy of it in my toolbox